# create groups from continuous variables with increments

Tags: r

I'm trying to create categorical groups from continuous variables with increments.

```
score <- sample(1:100,20,replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(score)
```

I want to create new categorical columns based on increments of 20 (exclusive) in score column. It would look something like: I also want the names of the new categorical columns to be in that format.

```
df <- df%>%
  mutate(G1_0_20 = case_when(score >= 0 & score <20 ~ 1),
         G2_20_40 = case_when(score >= 20 & score < 40 ~ 1),
         G3_40_60 = case_when(score >= 40 & score < 60 ~ 1),
         G4_60_80 = case_when(score >= 60 & score < 80 ~ 1),
         G5_80_100 = case_when(score >= 80 & score < 100 ~ 1))
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df
```

I'm wondering if there's a easier and faster way of creating this for a dataset that needs groups created from increments of 20 from values 0 to 4000.

Also, what if I want increments of 20 from values 0 to 100, and then increments of 100 from 200 to 300.

I would appreciate all the help there is! Thanks!!!

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question but may be of value: you could easily create these categories with `findInterval(df$score, c(seq(20, 100, 20), 200, 300))` - this would be a preferred format in some instances, for example if you are running a model or something and want to include age category instead of continuous age. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `cut` to create the grouping and then with `dummy_cols` from `fastDummies` create the dummy columns

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(fastDummies)
df %>%
   mutate(grp = cut(score, breaks = c(-Inf, seq(0, 4000, by = 20), Inf)), 
      grp = str_c("G", as.integer(droplevels(grp)), '_', 
      str_replace(grp, '\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\]', 
     '\\1_\\2'))) %>% 
   dummy_cols("grp", remove_selected_columns = TRUE) %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_remove(.x, 'grp_'), starts_with('grp_'))
```

-output

```
    score G1_0_20 G2_20_40 G3_40_60 G4_60_80 G5_80_100
1     20       1        0        0        0         0
2     99       0        0        0        0         1
3     44       0        0        1        0         0
4     28       0        1        0        0         0
5     63       0        0        0        1         0
6     88       0        0        0        0         1
7     44       0        0        1        0         0
8     59       0        0        1        0         0
9    100       0        0        0        0         1
10    55       0        0        1        0         0
11    37       0        1        0        0         0
12    54       0        0        1        0         0
13     6       1        0        0        0         0
14     7       1        0        0        0         0
15    48       0        0        1        0         0
16    88       0        0        0        0         1
17    97       0        0        0        0         1
18    10       1        0        0        0         0
19    65       0        0        0        1         0
20    18       1        0        0        0         0
```

Comment: Thanks! This works very well! Just one thing in terms of the names of the new groups. The fist group should start with G1 instead of G2, second one should start with G2 instead of G3, etc. how do I fix this?

Comment: @Bruh I think in that case, just add `droplevels` before doing `as.integer`

Comment: Thanks! The droplevels command does the job!

Answer (score 2):

For this we can use `dplyover::over()` and create a sequence to loop over with `seq()`. Disclaimer: The package is not on CRAN and I'm the maintainer.

The `.names` argument allows us to create nice names on the fly, we can use `{x_idx}` to access the number of the index element and `{x}` to access the value of the iteration.

The example below shows a sequence from `20` to `100` but we can generate any sequence by just replacing the numbers.

```r
set.seed(123)
score <- sample(1:100,20,replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(score)

library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/

df %>% 
  mutate(over(seq(20, 100, 20),
              ~ if_else(score < .x & score > (.x - 20), 1, 0),
              .names = "G{x_idx}_{x - 20}_{x}"
  ))
#>    score G1_0_20 G2_20_40 G3_40_60 G4_60_80 G5_80_100
#> 1     31       0        1        0        0         0
#> 2     79       0        0        0        1         0
#> 3     51       0        0        1        0         0
#> 4     14       1        0        0        0         0
#> 5     67       0        0        0        1         0
#> 6     42       0        0        1        0         0
#> 7     50       0        0        1        0         0
#> 8     43       0        0        1        0         0
#> 9     14       1        0        0        0         0
#> 10    25       0        1        0        0         0
#> 11    90       0        0        0        0         1
#> 12    91       0        0        0        0         1
#> 13    69       0        0        0        1         0
#> 14    91       0        0        0        0         1
#> 15    57       0        0        1        0         0
#> 16    92       0        0        0        0         1
#> 17     9       1        0        0        0         0
#> 18    93       0        0        0        0         1
#> 19    99       0        0        0        0         1
#> 20    72       0        0        0        1         0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: this works very well too! I do have the same question as the above answer by @akrun. How do I have the prefix to be G1 for group 1, G2 for group 2, etc.

Comment: @Bruh: We can use `{x_idx}` in the `.names` argument to increment `G`.

Answer (score 2):

in Base R:

```
a <- cut(df$score, seq(0,4000, 20))
G <- paste0(as.integer(a), sub("\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\]", "_\\1_\\2",a))
data.frame(score = df$score, model.matrix(~G+0))

  score G1_0_20 G2_20_40 G3_40_60 G4_60_80 G5_80_100
1     31       0        1        0        0         0
2     79       0        0        0        1         0
3     51       0        0        1        0         0
4     14       1        0        0        0         0
5     67       0        0        0        1         0
6     42       0        0        1        0         0
7     50       0        0        1        0         0
8     43       0        0        1        0         0
9     14       1        0        0        0         0
10    25       0        1        0        0         0
11    90       0        0        0        0         1
12    91       0        0        0        0         1
13    69       0        0        0        1         0
14    91       0        0        0        0         1
15    57       0        0        1        0         0
16    92       0        0        0        0         1
17     9       1        0        0        0         0
18    93       0        0        0        0         1
19    99       0        0        0        0         1
20    72       0        0        0        1         0
```